# Сделать условие по которому будет выводиться одна строка по значению, если данное значение повторяется в определенном интервале

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица в которой в столбце load_id значение повторяется 3 раза каждый день или в любое время.
мне нужно вывести одна строку с данным значением если она повторяется в интервале +-7 дней от даты в таблице. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробывал следующий код

```
select copy1.load_id
, copy1.dd
, copy1.mm
, copy1.yyyy
, copy1.w_name
, copy1.sum_detail
, copy1.sum_bal
, copy1.w_type
, copy1.prichina
, copy1.wd_name
from v_sea_motivation_vitisnenie copy1
   , v_sea_motivation_vitisnenie copy2
where copy1.load_id = copy2.load_id
and copy1.finish_date >= to_date('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
and copy1.finish_date between copy2.finish_date - interval '7' day
and copy2.finish_date + interval '7' day
group by copy1.load_id
, copy1.dd
, copy1.mm
, copy1.yyyy
, copy1.w_name
, copy1.sum_detail
, copy1.sum_bal
, copy1.w_type
, copy1.prichina
, copy1.wd_name
having count(copy1.load_id) > 1
order by 1, 2 ,3
```

но в данном случае дублирующиеся значения в столбце load_id вообще не показываются, показываются только не дублирующиеся. Есть мысль по поводу выборки с помощью MAX(finish_date) но мой кокос на шее не может выдать мне молочный коктейль с правильным вкусом)), помогите люди добрые

Comment: `DATEDIFF(finish_date, LAG(finish_date, 2))<=7`

Comment: Так как написан пример в моем случае  функция не работает ORA-30484 так как не хватает условий like   и over , и даже при указании функции Lag она не сработает так как шаг может быть от 1 до....

Comment: Это даже не пример - это идея, которую надо будет заложить в запрос. Понятно, что в финальном варианте все необходимые кляузы должны быть добавлены.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем поигравшись немного с кодом решил убить через maxdate
Вроде как при сверке файлов и расчетах через Excel данные получились одинаковые

```
having copy1.finish_date = max(copy2.finish_date)
```